# git bz error: 'bz' is not specified command

Tags: git, bugzilla

I have the **installation of git** `bz` as specified :

```
 cd ~
 git clone git://git.fishsoup.net/git-bz
 cp ~/git-bz/git-bz ~/.local/bin/
```

After committing the given patch, when I try to attach the given patch to the given bug for `bugzilla`. It shows the following error

> git: 'bz' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Any suggestion on this.

Comment: Is `~/.local/bin/` in your `PATH`? Check with `echo $PATH`. Is `~/.local/bin/git-bz` executable?

Comment: Yes it is in the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory where `git-bz` is should be either in your `$PATH` or in Git's exec-path. I suggest the later. You can put it in the right place using:

```
cp ~/git-bz/git-bz $(git --exec-path)/
```

(You may need to be root to run this, hence use `sudo` or `su`)

If you prefer putting it in your path, as noted by @Schwern, you can view the list of directories with `echo $PATH`. To add a directory to your `$PATH`, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path.

Comment: thank you, it has solved the problem. Can I know how this work?

Comment: When you type `git $command`, Git searches for a builtin-command named `$command`, and if it doesn't find it, it searches in several directories for an executable `git-$command`. The first is where Git is installed, called the exec-path (`git --exec-path` to see what directory it is for you), and then it searches in `$PATH` which is where the system (more precisely, the shell) searches for executables.